# how to fix my javascript text verification issue

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, textfield

I have a `textarea` in an html file. I am using the javascript code below. I want that when the user enters in the `textarea`the following sentences (with the break line),

```
hello
hi
how are you
```

javascript redirects him to a website. I tried to do this but didn't work. 
CAN ANYBODY PLEASE HELP ME?
THANKS IN ADVANCE:)

---

**Javascript code**

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
if (x === "hello" + \n + "hi" + \n + "how are you") {
  document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  return false;
 }
  else {
  alert('ok i knew it');
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: `\n`s should also be enclosed within quotes.

Comment: If you know what value to compare then put the value in the textarea, log its value in console and use this value for comparison in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape sequence have to be inside quotes:

```
if (x === "hello" + "\n" + "hi" + "\n" + "how are you") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
}
```

or simply:

```
if (x === "hello\nhi\nhow are you") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
}
```